# multiple height card layout with responsive (without fixed height)

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I need a multi-height card layout with responsive and no height should defined for each element

```html
<div id="container" class="cols">
    <div class="box one"></div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
    <div class="box one"></div>
    <div class="box three"></div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
    <div class="box five"></div>
    <div class="box one"></div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
    <div class="box six"></div>
    <div class="box three"></div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
</div>
```

**this is the code which i am trying i need same layout without any specfic height(dynamic height)**

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not for doing the work for you. You need to show an attempt yourself.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is "masonry". 

https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

Comment: angular-masonry or angular-material & its grids and cards would probably both be good starting points.

Comment: Each div should arrange automatically on the basis of dynamic content.for eg: consider 10 cards are there in my ui in that 3 can be collapsable so height should adjust automatically .in this case masnory fails why because they are using position as absolute..